# Transforming a table column using a function

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

i would like to run the `Web.Contents` function across a column containing urls (excel file downloads) in my table. I am hoping to transform this url column into a column of `Excel workbooks` by using `Web.Contents` and  then `Excel.Workbook` to convert the web contents into an excel workbook. I do not want to add a new/custom column.

The problem is when i try to do this using the code below, i get an expression error. I am not sure what i am doing wrong, i suspect i may be referring to the urls incorrectly within the `Web.Contents` function.

```
let
TransformedTable = Table.TransformColumns (Table, {"Urls", each Web.Contents([Urls])})
in
TransformedTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
= Table.TransformColumns (Table, {"Urls", each Web.Contents(_)})
```

Comment: Hi @Aleksei Zhigulin could you explain why my original expression did not work or point me to a resource where i can find the answer?

Comment: Hi. I guess, the reason is same as Table.TransformColumns can't refer to another columns (both formulas =Table.TransformColumns(Table, {"Urls", each [Urls_alt]}) and =Table.TransformColumns(Table, {"Urls", each [Urls]}) are not valid).

Comment: In that case, why is your one valid?, you did not refer to the column how does web contents know what to evaluate ?

Comment: I mean, syntax [ColumnName] is not valid for Table.TransformColumns.

Comment: I understand, do you know where i can find some resources to learn more about this. I could not find this information about the syntax in microsofts standard function documentation.

Comment: If you mean specifically this case - i didn't aware of such resources. If you mean the syntax generally - for instance, Ben Gribaudo's blog may be helpful: https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2017/12/08/4270/power-query-m-primer-part3-functions-function-values-passing-returning-defining-inline-recursion

Comment: I guess what i am trying to find out is how you knew the correct syntax forthe Table.TransformColumns function, because this syntax is not included in the documentation of the function.

Comment: Well, using shortcut _ is common practice in PQ to refer to each element of current object (for example, List.Transform({1..10}, each _*2)). Here you may find more information: https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2018/01/09/each-keyword-power-query/